# importing onmount along Jquery doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, import

I’m running into an error when importing onmount (https://github.com/rstacruz/onmount) using ES6 import statements alongside Jquery

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import onmount from 'onmount';
```

As the documentation mentions `It doesn't require jQuery, but if jQuery is found, it'll attach itself to it as $.onmount`

But i still get the following error when using $.onmount `jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.onmount is not a function`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Node or browser?

Comment: its seems to be the browser.